# Study the following courses in short span

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, abstract-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Due to my sudden love for mathematics I'm more inclined towards doing my post graduation in mathematics. It's not an impulsive decision rather a well thought and planned decision. I have fallen in love with mathematics and now I want to do my further studies in mathematics but for that I have to study the following courses in a span of just 6-7 months.

The courses are as follows :

1. Abstract algebra

[image: Abstract algebra]

2. Advanced calculus

   [image: Numerical analysis]
3. Differential equations

[image: DE]

4. Real analysis

[image: Real analysis]

5. Numerical analysis

[image: Numerical analysis]

I have to study all these courses on my own due to a clash. I don't know how to study on my own. Is it possible to study these courses on my own?

The university that I'm about to take admission has a prerequisite to pass all these courses with really good marks. How should I study to cover up my material in possible manner?

Also is it possible to study these courses in such a short span?

I really need guidance and I can't get it better guidance about this from anywhere else. Kindly help and please do not vote this question down or close because I really need help regarding these courses.

Please help me with whatever little you can. Your little help can help me do better.

Comment: @SpamIAm edited.

Comment: I perceive some inconsistencies in your question. On one hand "a well thought and planned decision" on the other hand "I don't know how to study on my own", and (in a comment to the posted answer) "go ahead and fight or shall I drop the weapons". So are you doing this or just talking? How far does it take to get there: The wise man answered "Walk,let me see how fast you walk,and then I will tell you!". If you could do it, then it is possible.You don't know how to study on your own,then start doing it and you will learn. If you have good books,and could devote 6 months to math, it could be done

Comment: @Mirko with "well thought and planned" I meant I took enough time to make a decision about my post graduation. Earlier I was more inclined towards computer science but now think I love mathematics more that computer science. And since it's a late decision so I have this hurdle to study the courses in a short span. And lastly the poem was really good.

Comment: I think people (myself included) are more enthusiastic about the idea of learning math than the process of actually learning it. Are you sure you are willing to spend multiple hours a day struggling with arcane symbols some of which has absolutely zero application to some of the hottest thing people are doing now or even natural science and physics? Are you in a good financial situation? Studying math is a privilege, and many people who do not have such a privilege go on to do great great things. Also, you will be burned out by the 40th page. One thing at a time and do it well is much better.

Answer (score 2):

That is a great amount 
to study in a short time.
It looks to me
to be (at least)
a full-time job.

Whatever you do,
do *not* go on
to the next one
until you are confident that
you understand the current one.

Make sure that you do
*lots* of exercises.

Find some practice
final exams and take them.
Do not continue until
you do well.

BTW, you have a copy
of the "Real Analysis" subjects
under "Abstract Algebra".

This is a
master's level sequence that
you want to learn.
Unless you are Terry Tao
or the equivalent,
I think that 6-7 months
is too short of a time
to do this.

I would recommend either
trying to learn less
or take more time.
Otherwise you may 
put too much pressure on yourself.

Comment: You are trying to say that to some it's not possible especially if you are studying on your own. But would you recommend me go ahead and fight or shall I drop the wearpons?

Comment: Start at the beginning and see how you do.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you say you have a clash.  Surely you can't have a clash for all 5 of these courses.  If so then your workload is already probably too much to study these on the side.  If mathematics is your true love, then it is the other side of the clash that should be suffering.

Also I presume you have some background in mathematics or else you would not even be considering it for later studies.  Hopefully you can build from what  you know.

The courses you mention are to some extent dependent on one another apart from abstract algebra which you can learn in isolation.  For the remainder, start with real analysis as it is the foundation of all the other courses.  You will need to understand this really well.  In order to cope with the rest.

Next proceed to advanced calculus  and then to differential equations and numerical analysis which you can study concurrently (and there is some overlap in the syllabus). Hopefully you have already seen some basic calculus and linear algebra or these will be tough.

I would strongly suggest discussing your plans with someone in the mathematics department who may be able to mentor you through this.

Comment: Going on your own is going to be difficult. You are missing the great insight and experience that good professors bring to a class. It would be difficult to have _Aha_ moments by just reading texts.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to study all of these courses on your own in this time span with other things going on in your life. Especially if you are not comfortable with self-study, and need to pass some sort of prerequisite exam.

The best advice, if this is the postgraduate route you want to take, is to postpone your bachelor's degree by a year to give you a chance to study these topics, and apply to your university of choice in the next round.